# Determine the print status c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to show message box after user click Print, I already tried the below code, but the message box did not appear.

```
void printToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
             PrintFile(sender, e);
         }

void PrintFile(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
             PrintDialog printDialog = new PrintDialog();

             printDocument1.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = true;
             printDialog.Document = printDocument1;
             printDialog.UseEXDialog = true;

             if (DialogResult.OK == printDialog.ShowDialog())
             {
                 printDocument1.DocumentName = "Document Page Print";
                 printDocument1.Print();

                 MessageBox.Show("Printed", "Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
             }
         }
```

I want to display that message box after the user click the print button like the below image:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
var result = printDialog.ShowDialog();

if (result == DialogResult.OK) { ... }
```